# Adjoint of a matrix operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

In my master course of operator theory of infinite dimensional linear systems, I am studying the equation $\mathcal{M}x=0$, where
$$
 \mathcal{M}:=\left( 
 \begin{array}{rcccc}
  \frac{d}{dt}&  0   & 0  & \frac{1}{c_1}   &  \frac{-1}{c_1}  
  \\ 
  0 & \partial_t & \partial_x & 0 &  0 
  \\ 
  0 & c_2\partial_x & \partial_t+\gamma \partial_{xx}^2  & 0  & 0 
  \\
  cD & 
   (\cdot)|_{b^+} \cdot \beta c  \, - (\cdot)|_{a^-} \cdot \alpha c &
  \alpha c_3\partial_x (\cdot)|_{a^-} -  \beta c_3\partial_x (\cdot)|_{b^+}   &
  \frac{d}{dt}+\lambda   D   &  
  -\lambda   D
  \\
  -cD &
  (\cdot)|_{b^+}\cdot \alpha c   - (\cdot)|_{a^-}  \cdot \beta c & 
  \beta c_3\partial_x (\cdot)|_{a^-} - \alpha c_3\partial_x (\cdot)|_{b^+} & 
  -\lambda   D  &  
  \frac{d}{dt} +\lambda   D
 \end{array}
 \right) ,
 $$
$x=(f_1(t),f_2(x,t),f_3(x,t),f_4(t),f_5(t))^T$, and $c$, $c_1,\,c_2,\,c_3,\,D,\, a,\,b,\alpha,\beta,\lambda,\gamma $ are positive constants and $b>a$.
I am trying to compute its adjoint operator, but I cannot.

I know the procedure, but here like appear evaluate terms as for instance $(\cdot)|_{a^-}$, I do not know how the procedure follows in this kind of cases.

Comment: I think you would have a better chance of getting an answer if you gave the simplest possible example which exhibits the issue, such as 2x2 or 1x1, not 5x5. Do you know what $(.)|_{a^-}$ means?

Comment: @KeithMcClary $((\cdot)|_{b^+}    - (\cdot)|_{a^-}  )\cdot f_2(x,t):= f_2(t,x)|_{b^+}   \, - f_2(t,x)|_{a^-}  $. If we consider for instance the 1x1 matrix defined for the expression before, how can I define its adjoint ?